# Why can't I write on RAX?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm trying to run this simple program:

```
int main (void) {
  __asm__ ("mov 123, %rax");
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles without problems and `objdump` confirms that the result is what I expect:

```
00000000004004ec <main>:
  4004ec:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ed:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f0:   48 8b 04 25 7b 00 00    mov    0x7b,%rax
  4004f7:   00 
  4004f8:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4004fd:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004fe:   c3                      retq
  4004ff:   90                      nop
```

However when I execute the program it segfaults exactly when executing `mov 0x7b,%rax`. The same happens if I use `%eax`. I'm wondering why?

Comment: As a tip, it was actually pretty obvious from the opcode: `48 8b 04 25 7b 00 00 00` is much too long to be a `mov imm32, reg64`. It quite clearly has `04 25` as modr/m+sib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, I found it a few seconds after posting the question. I forgot the `$` before the number (that was treated as an address).

The correct code is:

```
int main (void) {
  __asm__ ("mov $123, %rax");
  return 0;
}
```

Lesson learned: never code at night!

Comment: BTW, it's only luck that this returns `(0)`. The compiler might have opted to zero `%rax` before the assembly statement, with say: `xorl %eax, %eax`, for the return value - with no awareness that you had altered it.

Comment: @BrettHale: sure. The `return` statement was just to make compiler warnings go away.